# levy process and its characteristic function

Tags: measure-theory, characteristic-functions, levy-processes

Let $X(t)$ denote Levy Process.  It can be proves that c.f of $X(t)$ is given:

$E(e^{i\omega X(t)}) = e^{-\Phi(\omega)}$,

where

$ \Phi(\omega) = i \omega a - \int\limits^{-\infty}_{\infty} \frac{e^{i\omega x}-1-i\omega \tau(x)}{x^2} \, M(dx),$

$a$ being a real constant, $\tau(x)$ a centering function given by:

$\tau(x) = 
 \begin{cases} 
-1 & \mbox{dla } x < -1, \\ x, & \mbox{dla } |x| \le 1, \\ 1 & \mbox{dla } x > 1,
\end{cases}$

$M$ a canonical measure $M\{I\}<\infty$ for each bounded interval $I$, and

$M^+(x) = \int_{x^-}^{\infty} \frac{1}{y^2} M(dy) < \infty \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \        
M^-(-x) = \int_{-\infty}^{-x^+} \frac{1}{y^2} M(dy) < \infty$

Suppose that $M$ has no atom at the origin and

$
\alpha = \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} \, M(dx) < \infty
$

We can then write

$M^+(x) = \alpha[1-B(x-)], \ \ \ \  \ \ \ M^-(-x) = \alpha B(-x)  (x>0),
$

where $B(x)$ is a distribution function.

Proof that one can simplify $\Phi(\omega)$ to

$
\Phi(\omega) = - i \omega d - \alpha \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} (e^{i \omega x} - 1) \, dB(x)
$

Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "$x^-$" for a real number $x$?

Comment: One-sided limit

Comment: Limit of a real-number....?

Comment: One side limit of a function in a certein point. For example consider cumulative distribution function . It is posiible to write $F(x^-)$ and $x$ is a real number. Comming back to my question you can treat this integral as a function dependig on $x$ or so I believe.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks.